# Accessing the value of eclipse classpath variable M2_REPO in run configuration VM arguments

Tags: eclipse, classpath, maven-3, openjpa

In the run configuration of eclipse, you are provided with a set of default variables that you can use in the VM arguments, like `container_path` and `env_var`.
What I want to access is a classpath variable, `M2_REPO`, but can't see a way of doing this. I need to specify a javaagent in the VM arguments, which requires a path to a jar file. This jar file lives in the maven repository, but I can't find a way of specifying the path to the maven repository using the already configured `M2_REPO` Classpath variable (configured in `windows`->`preferences`->`java`->`Build Path`->`Classpath variable`).
  What I would like to do is use this as my VM arguments but can't because `classpath_var` isn't a real variable.

```
-javaagent:${classpath_var:M2_REPO}/org/apache/openjpa/openjpa/2.1.0/openjpa-2.1.0.jar
```

Is there any other way of accessing the value of `M2_REPO` in VM arguments?

Comment: Just in case someone else missreads the question as I did: `${env_var:VAR_NAME}` can be used. Since my repo is under `%M2_HOME%`, this works for me: `-javaagent:${env_var:M2_HOME}/repository/org/apache/openjpa/openjpa/2.1.0/openjpa-2.1.0.jar`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but it worked for us as a way of sharing a codebase and not having hard coded paths in our run configurations. Rather than using a classpath variable, use a string substitution variable (configured in `windows -> preferences -> run/debug -> String Substitution`). Set it to the same path as the value of M2_REPO and save. Using the above example if your string substitution variable name was also M2_REPO, the VM Argument would be

```
-javaagent:${M2_REPO}/org/apache/openjpa/openjpa/2.1.0/openjpa-2.1.0.jar
```

To be even more clear, I would personally just create an openjpa_2_1_0_agent string substitution variable that went directly to your open jpa jar.