# Can the Maven Eclipse Plugin use M2_REPO classpath variable for source path?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm using the Maven Eclipse Plugin to generate my .classpath file. The jar paths are expressed relative to the M2_REPO classpath variable.

path="M2_REPO/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar" ...

The problem is when I specify to download the sources, the resultant file contains references to hardcoded directories instead of using the M2_REPO classpath variable.

value="jar:file:/C:/Users/Me/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16-javadoc.jar!/"/>

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's said in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8265160/3890673) to use `${env_var:M2_HOME}` but that does not work for me. (neither does `${env_var:M2_REPO}`, btw). Maybe a problem of my local configuration and maybe this works for you. Or did you find a solution yet?

An alternative which requires manual work for each setup: Go to Preferences -> Run/Debug -> String Substitution -> New, enter M2_REPO and select the "repository"-folder: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEEHe.jpg Now you can use ${M2_REPO}.

Comment: I have no problem using M2_REPO. The problem is when Maven regenerates my .classpath file. It is incorrectly generated (I guess).